# bootstrap 4 Grid, laying 4 elements in a row with a custom horizontal gutter

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I am trying to lay 4 elements in a row with a custom horizontal gutter, I tried to put each element in a col with the class of `col-md-2` for a certain screen size, and modify the margin-right of each element to my need.. but it didn't look very good, when applying the `col-md-3` obviously there is no room for adding a margin to each element, surprisingly when I tried applying `col-md-2.5` class, it worked on big screens, however, when I want to have the element span to 10 cols in the smaller screens, it does, but when i go back to the bigger screen, it behaves like the small screen again, Here is my HTML code and i will leave a screenshot down below to illustrate the behavior that I want.

```css
[class^="col"]:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 60px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-2.5">1</div>
        <div class="col col-md-2.5">2</div>
        <div class="col col-md-2.5">3</div>
        <div class="col col-md-2.5">4</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--I know it may look weird but this above HTML along with the CSS 
achieved my goal on the big screens -->

<!-- things get messy again when i do the following to adjust the 
view of elements on smaller screens -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-md-2.5">1</div>
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-md-2.5">2</div>
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-md-2.5">3</div>
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-md-2.5">4</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- it works fine in small screen, but when I back to big 
screens with this set up, it doesn't give me the initial 
behavior and spans every element to columns !!
```

**Here is the screenshot of the desired behavior**

[image]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get your problem. Have you just tried simply applying paddings to the left and right of your 4 columns using `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}` notation?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#notation

That way you don't have to use `offset` on your columns. Instead, you can just use `col`.

For example, if you only want big left and right paddings on large scrren, you can apply `px-lg-5` on `col` class.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col px-lg-5">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col px-lg-5">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col px-lg-5">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col px-lg-5">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/241204/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your target screen:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-md-2.5">1</div>
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-md-2.5">2</div>
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-md-2.5">3</div>
        <div class="col-10 offset-1 col-md-2.5">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add whichever size you want: xs, sm, md, lg to the col and the offset like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-2.5">1</div>
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-2.5">2</div>
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-2.5">3</div>
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-2.5">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a reference:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

EDIT: It looks like you may have to specify which screen you're targeting when using the offset class. But, you're correct about not needing the other option.

Comment: thanks for your response, but like I mentioned in the title, this is bootstrap 4, and it automatically considers the `col` as a `col-xs` in bootstrap 3. so this still didn't solve my issue, but thanks anyway

Comment: Pays attention to details...Leaves room for improvement. Haha thanks for being so nice about it. Now you've piqued my curiosity on the matter.